# ¿Como puedo ejecutar un metodo despues de otro?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

tengo una duda si esto posible. Tengo dos listas desplegables, pero están divididos en 2 métodos distintos ya que cada uno tiene diferentes funciones.

Me pregunta es que no se si es posible declarar el llamado del mismo. Como por ejemplo;

```
private void Dropdownlist()
{
//Lista desplegable
//Cuando se eliga Item #1 ejecutar el solo el Método Habilitar_uno
//Cuando se eliga item #2 Ejecutar el solo el Método Habilitar_dos
}

 public void Habilitar_uno(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 //funciones
 }

 public void Habilitar_uno(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 //Funciones

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a esto, y si no es, explicar mejor lo que buscas. :D

```
private void Dropdownlist()
{
        var valor = ddl1.Value;
        if (valor == "algo")
        {
               ddl2.DataSource = Cargar1();
               ddl2.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
               ddl2.DataSource = Cargar2();
               ddl2.DataBind();
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh ya, muchas gracias!, me resolvistes la duda con la parte de ddl2.DataSource = Cargar2();

Comment: entonces dale like!!!! XD

Comment: Para la proxima, aun no puedo. xD